# ElasticSearch 2.x _boost field in type mapping is deprecated

Tags: elasticsearch

In according with [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-boost-field.html) the _boost field in mapping will be automatically removed.
So I could rewrite this in according with new version of elasticsearch?

```
mappings:
        name : { boost: 1, analyzer: my_analyzer }
```

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Query-Time Boosting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/query-time-boosting.html) instead.

It seems that is still possible to boost at index time, [check it out](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-boost.html), but the same page tells why it's a bad idea.

Comment: So I have to specify boost everytime I execute query. It doesn't seems to be worth.